# How to install Groovy on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test Morse simulator recently. Since Morse only support Ubuntu 13.04 or later, I wonder if there is any approach to install Groovy on Ubuntu 13.04? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64032/how-to-install-groovy-on-ubuntu-13.04/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A cleaner option is probably [building what you need from source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source).

That will be more work for you, but is more likely to produce a reliable result than installing binaries that were built for a different Ubuntu version.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install Groovy by using the same repository quantal uses; however, I caution you with this. I did it, but it works only after doing some things first.

To begin, you must install qt4, NOT qt5. It will not work with qt5 (at least, for my purposes it hasn't). Also note that there might be some unexpected issues in the future with this... But, try it. It's working fine for me.

One more thing: you will need to link python correctly. Run this command:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

This will fix the python linking. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't directly answer the question, but MORSE does not just support Ubuntu 13.04.  I'm currently running it on several 12.04 systems.  As long as you have cmake, Python 3.2, and Blender >2.62 MORSE should run.  See the installation instructions at: http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/latest/user/installation.html

EDIT:
I think the confusion might be in the fact that Morse 1.0 is only available in the package manager for Ubuntu 13.04 and newer.  Morse 0.6 can be installed on previous versions using the package manager.  MORSE 1.0 can be installed (very easily) from source on older versions.  Things might have changed with 1.0, but on previous versions the version in the package manager did not support ROS.  You had to build from source to enable ROS middleware support.  The MORSE mailing list would be a better place to get an answer to that question.

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-31**:
Back-porting MORSE to a system on which Groovy is officially supported, may well be the easiest solution.